# Install macOS High Sierra using Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal

I've been trying to find a way to install macOS High Sierra using terminal to install it on various computers quickly. It can be done with macOS Sierra and OS X El Capitan after mounting the InstallESD.dmg file in the directory Install macOS Sierra.app/Contents/SharedSupport using the following code in terminal:

```
installer -allowUntrusted -pkg Volumes/OS\ X\ Install\ ESD/Packages/OSInstall.mpkg -target Volumes/Macintosh\ HD
```

I've tried using the same methods to install High Sierra, but it always gives the following error:

The OS Install failed with error: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=0 "Undefined error:0

There aren't many articles online for finding a solution to this issue, but there are many about creating a bootable drive. Thank you in advance for the answers.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I’m having the same issue.

Comment: Same problem here even with properly formed POSIX path (ie, leading `/`).

Answer (score 2):

You can run:

```
sudo /Applications/Install\ macOS\ High\ Sierra.app/Contents/Resources/startosinstall –applicationpath /Applications/Install\ macOS\ High\ Sierra.app
```

Info from OWC Article: [Click Here To See](http://blog.macsales.com/42884-is-it-possible-not-to-convert-to-apfs-when-upgrading-to-high-sierra)

Answer (score -1):

Unlike previous versions, the High Sierra installer requires a "POSIX-ly correctly formed" path to the locations of both the installation source and the installation target. Adding a leading "/" to each occurrence of "Volumes" should eliminate the error.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't actually help or resolve the issue. `sudo installer -allowUntrusted -pkg /Volumes/InstallESD/Packages/OSInstall.mpkg -target /Volumes/Target\ Drive/` yields the same resultant error as noted above.

Comment: @E. Bauer: Six months later, and of no real value as to timeliness, but... It seems that error code 0 in the NSPOSIXErrorDomain gets thrown during OS High Sierra installation only when the installation is being attempted on non-Apple hardware. These "various computers" are all Macs, right?

Comment: Yep, they're bonafide Mac Pros on my end @doc-g.

Comment: @ylluminate: Thanks--since it's true in your case, it was likely true for the OP as well.