# Install macOS Big Sur using Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal

This command was [working previously in macOS High Sierra](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/300264/install-macos-high-sierra-using-terminal/324459#) to install the OS via Terminal:

```
sudo /Applications/Install\ macOS\ Big\ Sur.app/Contents/Resources/startosinstall -applicationpath /Applications/Install\ macOS\ Big\ Sur.app
```

But I'm getting:

> "--applicationpath" is deprecated in macOS 10.14 and greater. Please remove it from your invocation.

Comment: What do you want that you can’t get by a double-click on the icon?  `open ______.app` is effectively the same in most situations.

Comment: Not when I'm going to do that on 50 macs :)

Comment: Which isn’t “most situations” and wasn’t mentioned in your question.  Hence the request for detail.

Answer (score 5):

This seems to work:

```
sudo /Applications/Install\ macOS\ Big\ Sur.app/Contents/Resources/startosinstall --agreetolicense --nointeraction --forcequitapps
```

Answer (score -1):

I advise you to begin by :

```
/Applications/Install\ macOS\ Big\ Sur.app/Contents/Resources/startosinstall --usage
```

to have more informations on options of command line.